# string assignments in structs

Tags: c++, string, struct, variable-assignment

I wanna know how should I assign a string to a string member of a struct.
for example :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
string c="salam";
struct man{
    string name;
}*mary;
int main(){
    string b ="HI";

    (*mary).name=b;

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work but I need this kind of assignment. I have string that I do some operations on it and wanna assign it to one of the members of my struct...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `mary` is a pointer, yes. But what does it point to?

Comment: You have the assignment correct.  You just need create an object for mary to point at.  mary = new man;  you can also refer to the name element as mary->name.

Comment: Wow, this question totally got _Lounged_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *Lounge The Missiles!*

Comment: but the main problem is here:
I have a linked list and I need using pointers in my main program and also I need to assign strings to the node->next, here is the complete code:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6661872/
and the problem is with line 87 and 88
so sorry I couldn't explain my question well ...
an thank you very much for your answers :)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not with the string; it is with your attempted use of structures. You created a pointer-to-`man`, not a `man`.

Here's how to define a type called `man`, then create an *instance* of that type called `mary`, then assign a value to the member of that type called `name`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct man
{
   string name;
};

int main()
{
   man mary;
   mary.name = "HI";
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but can see where (perhaps) somebody would have considered the using directive worthy of a downvote.

Comment: @Jerry: Granted. I considered switching it out for qualified namespace usage, but decided that might be a step too far on this occasion.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Nonsense, the downvote was probably for indenting with 3 spaces.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Unfortunately web browsers are not optimised for program code, so I cannot take the _proper_ approach of tab indentation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If I'm not mistaken, stack overflow supports tab indentation!

Comment: @FredOverflow: But in the absence of decent code viewing tools in web browsers, they will look poor to most viewers. So, unfortunately, we are stuck with a sort of "rendered snapshot" of indentation rendered at a fixed width.